# Can someone tell me if they see this

Tags: javascript

I am having problems when I try to pull it up on my computer the page is blank. I am not understanding this. Like when you click on the file button on the internet and you click open file that file shows up blank. Can someone help me understand why it is doing that. Thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
     <title>Week 10</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      / *<![CDATA[ */
      Var name;
     firstName = "Valerie";
     lastName ="Shipbaugh";
     var placeOfBirth;
     name=FirstName +"";
     name += lastName;
      placeOfBirth ="Houston";
     placeOfBirth +=",Texas";
     nameArray = name.split("");
     /*]]>*/
    </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       //<![CDATA[

     document.write("<p> My first name is : + nameArray[0]
     + "<br />");

    document.write("My last name is: "+ nameArray[1]
    + "<br />");
    */
     The brackets[] specifies alternate characters allowed in a patch pattern.
      It uses metacharacters which are special characters that define the pattern      matching rules ina  regular experession.
     */ 

   document.write("There are " + firstName.length
   + " characters in my first name" + " <br/>");
    */
    This one called the length property.
     This returns the number of characters in a string.

    */
    document.write("I was born in " + placeOfBirth + " <br/>");
    */ 
    With this string we are using concatenation operations.
      */
     document.write("<p>My initials are: " + firstName.charAt(0) +
     lastName.charAt(0) + "</p>"); 
     */ 
     The last one return the character at the specific position in a text string
    returns an empty string if the specified position is greater than the length of the string.
      */

    //]]>
   </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

So where my comments are to explain what is going on is in the wrong place???

Comment: You need to make sure all your commented blocks are matching, i.e. /* and */, and your quotes don't match either. Not to mention `Var` needs to always be `var`, and your variable names are case-sensitive too.

Comment: your codes are badly formatted with too many comments and syntax error within javascript.  Also badly placed as well.

Comment: surely the editor you used to type this indicated in some way that the comments were off? wrong syntax highlighting or something similar?

Comment: @Andre - No, it's all IE's fault. </sarcasm>

Comment: Comments are not properly nested/written. What editor are you using, if you using just a text editor try to use a notepad++ or other editor that will show syntax highlighting. Also why your script looks like that.. Read some good programming practices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive - so in the first section of your scripts:

```
Var name;                      //var is with a lowecase "v"
firstName = "Valerie";
lastName ="Shipbaugh";
var placeOfBirth;
name=FirstName +"";            //firstName was created with a lowecase "f"
```

Later you have this...

```
document.write("<p> My first name is : + nameArray[0]
 + "<br />");
```

You're missing a quote in there, should be
    document.write("

My first name is : " + nameArray[0]
     + "
");

And finally, comments open and close like this:

```
/* comment */
```

Not like this

```
*/ error */
```

Fixing these things will make the script run.  However, it's not doing what I suspect you want.  You are trying to split() the string containing the name, but there's nothing to split it on.  You need to add a space between then and try this:

```
nameArray = name.split(" ");
```

You can see this working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/CM7fx/

Answer (score 2):

Of course it won't work, the comment blocks aren't even right:

```
 */
 The brackets[] specifies alternate characters allowed in a patch pattern.
  It uses metacharacters which are special characters that define the pattern
  matching rules ina  regular experession.
 */
```

Should be:

```
 /*
 The brackets[] specifies alternate characters allowed in a patch pattern.
  It uses metacharacters which are special characters that define the pattern
  matching rules ina  regular experession.
 */
```

Also, you really should avoid using `document.write`. In certain cases, that is what causes a blank page (if I remember correctly, when you use it after page load).

Comment: I am still learning javascript and we have to use the document.write

Comment: @ErikPerik - That's why I said "after page load". I've had to deal with cases in the past where the use of `document.write` caused severe complications from my side (namely joomla injecting javascript in post content, thus my inability to simply embed the post via ajax, since as we said, it cleared the page).

Answer (score 2):

Look at errors reported by the browser (tools->error console in firefox for example) it will hi-light errors such as you mismatched `/**/` comments & the missing closing quote character from;

```
document.write("<p> My first name is : + nameArray[0]
```

Also js is case sensitive so its `var` not `Var`, which you should use to define all your variables such as `firstname` (which you incidentally later refer to as `Firstname`) etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more general way to solve this problem:

1. Take everything out of this file and
   copy it into notepad.
2. Put just the
   `<html>`and `</html>` into the file
3. Begin copying very small blocks into
   the file one at a time, each time
   reload the page
4. Soon you will see
   one *small* block that causes the
   failure, then you can assess that
   small block.

Comment: +1 for splitting task in small chunks. That said, he's got severe coding issues there, which gives the impression he can't actually fix them even if they were small separate issues - a clear example of this is the comment blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Test in multiple browsers and make sure you have javascript enabled id' suggest first

Comment: Yeh i've just run this and too and the comment blocks are wrong. Plus you get errors when you try and run it. Make sure script debugging is enabled as well if in IE

Answer (score 0):

The comments were wrong, the variable name are case sensitive. Here is a working version without comments, you can re-add those

```
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
     <title>Week 10</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var name;
            var firstName = "Valerie";
            var lastName ="Shipbaugh";
            var placeOfBirth;

            name= firstName + " " + lastName;
            placeOfBirth ="Houston ,Texas";
            var nameArray = name.split(" ");
        </script>
    </head>
     <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">

        document.write("<p> My first name is : " + nameArray[0] + "<br />");

        document.write("My last name is: " + nameArray[1] + "<br />");

        document.write("There are " + firstName.length + " characters in my first name" + " <br/>");

        document.write("I was born in " + placeOfBirth + " <br/>");

        document.write("<p> My initials are: " + firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.charAt(0) + "</p>"); 
   </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Oh and the split function takes a string in of what to look for and split by. You have an empty string, you needed a space character.